# For what prime numbers $p\gt2$ number $2^{2^p} -1$ is divisible by $p$?

Tags: number-theory

For what prime numbers $p\gt2$ number $2^{2^p} -1$ is divisible by $p$?
Is it correct:
$2^{2^p} \equiv 1\pmod{p}\Rightarrow \phi(p)=p-1|2^p$ and hence $p-1=2^x$ so $p$ must be of the form $2^x+1$.

Comment: No, a counterexample is $p=641$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $$2^{2^p}\equiv 1\mod p$$ then either there must be some positive integer $m<p$ with $$2^{2^m}\equiv -1\mod p$$ or we have $p=3$. To see this consider $$2^{2^{p-1}}\equiv \pm 1\mod p$$ If the result is $1$ , continue. If $$2^{2^1}\equiv 1\mod p$$ we have $p=3$. Hence, $p$ must divide some Fermat number.

Now suppose , $p$ divides some Fermat number , that means $$2^{2^m}\equiv -1\mod p$$ We clearly must have $m<p$ because every prime factor of a Fermat number $F_n:=2^{2^n}+1$ must have the form $2^{n+2}\cdot k+1$ , hence must exceed $n$ . This implies $$2^{2^p}\equiv 1\mod p$$

Hence exactly the prime factors of the Fermat numbers satisfy the desired congruence.

Comment: Nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

It is crucial to consider the logic and deduction in our proofs, because it is the basis of Math and what makes it so beautiful;
I think that what you proved that is
$$p=2^x + 1 \implies p|(2^{2^p}-1)$$
but not
$$p|(2^{2^p}-1) \implies p=2^x + 1$$
and we know that the two statements are not equivalent. So, your conclusion is not completely correct.

As @Peter said in the comments, there's a counterexample $p=641$, it works, but $p \ne2^x+1$. However, we know $p=3,5,17,\dots$ all work, because (for example with $17$)
$$16|2^{17}, \ 2^{17}=(17-1)\cdot2^{13} \implies 2^{2^{17}} \equiv (2^{17-1})^{2^{13}}\equiv1 \pmod{17}$$
But $2^{641} \equiv0 \pmod{128}$ and $2^{641}\equiv2 \pmod{5}$ and thus by the chinese remainder theorem,
$$2^{641} \equiv 512 \pmod{640} \implies 2^{641}=640k+512$$
$$\implies 2^{2^{641}}\equiv2^{512} \equiv(2^{64})^8 \equiv1^8 \equiv1\pmod{641}$$
So, for your condition to be satisfied, we have to have $2^p \equiv m\pmod{p-1}$ and so $2^m \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ where $m<p-1$ is a non-negative integer.

What I advise you to consider is the order of $2$ modulo $p$, because if ${\rm ord}_p({n})|m$ then your condition would be correct.