# Is there a calculable alternative for totient function when the base is $2$?

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

Inspired by this question [For any odd number, $n$, does there always exist $k$ such that $2^k-1$ is a multiple of $n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4086591/399263), I searched for duplicates and there are many, all having almost invariably the same answer involving Euler's theorem and totient function.

My exact question is the following:

> given $n$ odd, does there exist a calculable function $f(n)$ which would not involve the knowledge of the prime factors of $n$ such that $2^{f(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$

Obviously $f(n)$ is a multiple of $\lambda(n)$ the Carmichael function, and I know it is not possible to solve the more general problem $a^{f(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$ for any base $a$ since this would be a hack against the RSA encryption system (and this would be known...), but is it at least possible when $a=2$ ?

I have seen in this thread [For what prime numbers $p\gt2$ number $2^{2^p} -1$ is divisible by $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3700450/399263) that $f(n)=2^n$ is possible for certain values of $n$ but not all.

Note, that this is mainly out of curiosity, I suspect though that it might be impossible too.

Comment: One slight remark : Should there be anyone able to hack RSA , I fear he / she would not tell it. Base $2$ in fact does not help. That Mersenne numbers are factored upto a very high limit has the reason that countless people worked on this project. The question with the below link might be something different.

Comment: Trusting that $n$ is odd, you can always test $n-1$.  If that fails, then at least you will have learned that $n$ is composite, which might be useful.

Comment: Double Mersennes fit $2n^2+4n+1$ where $n$ is the previous value ... is that along where you want ?

Comment: ok, thanks for the comments.